# Progress bar with Vue and Axios object

Tags: vue.js, axios, javascript-objects

I would like to create an upload progress bar with Axios.

Everything is working fine with server sending and response.

The problem is that I don't know how to capture the progress percentage (which is correctly calculated) from my exported object.

My file upload.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:80/upload.php'

const config = {
  Headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
  onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
    return parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100))
  }
}

export default {
  send (data) {
    return axios.post(baseUrl, data, config)
  }
}
```

My Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>File:</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" ref="file" @change="changeFile()" />
    <button @click="submit()">Upload</button>
    <br />
    <progress max="100" :value.prop="uploadPercentage"></progress>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import upload from '../services/upload.js'
  export default {
    name: 'Upload',
    data: () => ({
      file: null,
      uploadPercentage: 0
    }),
    methods: {
      submit () {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', this.file)
        upload.send(formData)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data)
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log('Failure')
        })
      },
      changeFile () {
        this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

How to retreive, from the component *submit* method, the info sent by the *onUploadProgress* in order to update the data *uploadPercentage*?

Thanks.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function to your send operation that will be called later.

See example below

```js
const config = {
  Headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
  onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
    var progress= parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100));
    if (config.onProgress)
        config.onProgress(progress);
  }
}

export default {
  send (data, onProgress) {
    config.onProgress= onProgress;
    return axios.post(baseUrl, data, config)
  }
}
```

Then you upload code will be

```js
upload.send(formData,(pogress)=>{
    // Update your uploadPercentage here
})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('Failure')
  })
```

Comment: Glad i could help.